# Straight lines - pair of straight lines

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
What is the product of the length of the perpendiculars drawn from the point $(1,1)$ to the pair of lines $x^2 + xy - 6y^2 = 0$

I really don't even know how to approach this problem. Please help!

Comment: I think you might mean $x^2+xy-6y^2=0$.

Comment: Probably you know how to compute the distance from a point to a line.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes that I do know.

Comment: Well, the two lines are $x+3y=0$ and $x-2y=0$.

Comment: Ummmm how did you get that? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Factored $x^2+xy-6y^2$.

Comment: Oh.... Well that was easy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well you got most of your answer. to factorize it i used 
$(ax + by)(cx + dy)$
expanded it and compared to your equation . 
so$$ac =1$$
$$bc + ad = 1$$
$$bd =-6$$

Comment: i would love to know if there is a better way to do this